# Windows virtual machine for Mac students to share

Tags: mac, windows, virtualization

I am a teacher in a Windows-supported college university, where we use a lot of software that only runs on Windows computers. We would like to help our Mac students by providing them with an easy-to-use and easy-to-transfer way to run Windows as a virtual machine, preferably without to need to install or configure a lot of software for the student.

Does somebody have an idea of a way in which we can create and configure a virtual machine and provide it to the students for simple use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using transfer of virtual machines,

First create one virtual machine on Your computer and install necessary os and softwares into it,

Then transfer this virtual machine backup to your students Macs (Ask them to use same VM player that you used to make that VM) Also provide the login credentials of VM os.

Here is detailed description for [VirtualBox](http://ccm.net/faq/40899-virtualbox-how-to-transfer-a-virtual-machine-to-another-host-computer) but you are free to use any VM Player, Hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful information. Is it possible to create a VM in Windows and transfer it to a Mac? Or do I need to create it on a Mac in order to transfer it to my students?

Comment: You can create VM on any OS and transfer to any other OS. Provided you are using the same VM player.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact same need and for security testing (of vulnerability of different operating systems), I evaluated many virtualization environments.

I finally adopted [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) because it was able to run many Windows versions, many Linux versions without too many usability and configuration problems. From a security standpoint and from a teacher standpoint the ease of use is a wining point.

As a security engineer I test operating systems under condition where they die (most notably weapons against Windows), and VirtualBox survived.

For a teacher, here are 2 more pieces of advice:

- To correctly help your students working with Mac, it would be easier for you to work with the same environment.
- Software which are running on different operating systems (MacOS X and Linux) are usually of a better software quality and stability and better suited to make student work on them.

VirtualBox will let you save a virtual operating state image which could contain softwares already suitably configured for your students to save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. The software we use is not our (the teachers) own choice. It is the university college that determines which software to use (mostly based on the price tag attached).